# How to set up Nord VIM Color Scheme?

Tags: vim

I am dabbling with vim and am trying to change the color scheme to the Nord theme. However, it seems like some of the colors and the background color are not working. I tried using the Dracula theme, and that works fine. Is there something I am missing when setting up this particular color scheme? Is there something else I need to configure? As at least some of the colors change when setting the color scheme to Nord, I believe the installation is not a problem.

I am not sure if this information is useful, but I am just using the terminal app  on mac OSX High Sierra 10.13.6. For vim, I am using vim 8.2 and vim-plug for the plugins.

[Nord installation page with what it should look like](https://www.nordtheme.com/docs/ports/vim/installation) vs. [My terminal with Nord kind of working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykYZT.png)

This is all I have in my .vimrc so far.

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'
call plug#end()

syntax on
colorscheme nord
set background=dark
set nu
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many color schemes in Vim require that your terminal is also configured with the corresponding color theme and this is the case with the Nord color scheme. From the page you linked to:

> Vim in terminal mode must be used with a Nord terminal emulator theme in order to work properly!

This happens because terminals traditionally only used to support 16 colors and many terminal programs tend to stick with using 16 colors only. Many theme authors will select the 16 colors that will work for other terminal programs and will end up restricting Vim to the same 16 colors since they're used elsewhere too.

If you'd prefer not to change the theme of your terminal and use the Nord color scheme *only* in Vim, it's still possible to do so (assuming your terminal supports 24-bit colors, which most modern terminals actually do.)

Simply add the following to your vimrc (probably best to add it before the `colorscheme` command):

```
set termguicolors
```

This instructs Vim to ignore the terminal color settings and use the settings meant to the GUI version of Vim instead. The GUI color specifications use 24-bit colors, with 8-bits for RGB each, that's why support for 24-bit colors on the terminal is essential to make this work.

Additionally, some themes actually ship two color presets, one for dark background and one for light background. You can use `set bg=dark` or `set bg=light` to explicitly request one of these two modes.

([This page](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728#not-supporting-true-color) suggests that Terminal.app doesn't support 24-bit color, but iTerm2 on the Mac supports it, so you might want to consider switching to that, which is a good idea anyways since iTerm2 has generally more features than the built-in Terminal.app.)

Comment: `set termguicolors` did not help to resolve the problem.

Comment: @AinTohvri Unfortunately, your feedback is not really actionable... Are you trying to the same nord-vim theme? Are you also on the Mac OS platform, using Vim 8.2 on the Terminal.app? If your platform, version of Vim, or colorscheme is different, this solution might not apply directly to you...

Comment: Yup, Vim 8.2, macOS Catalina, default Terminal app, but with Vim in `tmux`. I also escalated a ticket on GitHub directly to follow up on this mishap. For those interested: https://github.com/arcticicestudio/nord-vim/issues/236

Comment: @AinTohvri Looking at the GH ticket and now re-reading my answer I now see I mentioned at the top that the Nord colorscheme requires a matching terminal theme (like they said there.) I also wrap up by mentioning the native Terminal app in Mac OS doesn't support 24-bit color (which is what `'termguicolors'` requests), so it won't work there. Either loading the terminal theme or switching to a more capable iTerm2 should fix that for you. (Personally, I recommend the latter, regardless of whether you also want the terminal theme.)

Comment: Thanks! Installing `Nord.terminal` profile in `Terminal.app` worked out and the scheme is working. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: `set termguicolors` worked for me, thank you!